# How to confirm paymentIntent only if item is available / stripe

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm using react-native / firebase / stripe.
I'm building a marketplace app, with customer to customer sell.
When a customer buy a product ( there is only 1 available) , i'm getting a server notification from stripe to tell me that the paymentIntent has been confirmed.
I check if the firebase doc is still available, if so, then i move it to another collection.
If the doc is not available it means someone has already bought the article. In this case i have 2 customers who bought the same article. I have to refund the second one but i will be loosing the stripe fees. Is there any way to avoid this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're only accepting card payments but if you are then you should probably look into this guide here [1] where you confirm the PaymentIntent server-side. This would allow you to check if you have inventory before confirming the PaymentIntent.

If you're not just accepting card payments, then there's a beta [2] here for a similar flow that would allow you to run custom actions before confirming a PaymentIntent.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously?platform=react-native

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/run-custom-actions-before-confirmation

Comment: thats exactly what i was loooking for thank you